# MVVMCross How to get ViewModel Instance within View Code Behind

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm using MVVMCross 7.1.2 and have a situation where several of my pages can't inherit the `MvxContentPage` class. Understandably this breaks a few things that MVVMCross implements.

One thing I noticed is the `BindingContext` for the page does not get set and as a result we get a NullReference exception which is difficult to debug.

What is the best was to access the ViewModel Instance form the Views code behind ? At the moment I'm using the interface `IMvxOverridePresentationAttribute` and then implementing it like this:

```
public MvxBasePresentationAttribute PresentationAttribute(MvxViewModelRequest request)
{
    BindingContext = ((MvxViewModelInstanceRequest) request).ViewModelInstance;
    InitializeComponent(); <--- Update 1,moved from ctor
    return null;
}
```

Is this the best way to get the VM instance ? or is there a better to the `BindingContext` automatically set.

UPDATE 1;
I still get the `NullReference` Exception with this method presumably as it sets the `BindingContext` after `InitializeComponent` is called. I've tried moving the `InitializeComponent` call to after the `BindingContext` is set but the page doesn't render correctly.

Comment: First none of the pages that inherits from `MvvmCross.Forms` have `BindingContext` property, MvvmCross use `DataContext` instead [check this](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross.Forms/Views/MvxContentPage.cs#L20). Second, from any code behind that inherits from any `MvxPage` you could access to the viewmodel by simply call `this.ViewModel`. Third explain better what are you tring to acomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but these pages are of type ContentPage. I am not able to inherit any other type due to a control which is used on these pages.

Comment: Why not ? which kind of control don't allow you to use the `MvxContentPage` ? Never happens that to me before

Comment: There are several Views in the project which use Syncfusions SfBackdropPage and unfortunately this is the base for these Views, this control inherits from ControlPage itself. So simply I need to wire up the BindingContext manually, unless there is another way of course.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this?

```
public partial class SomeView : ContenPage
{
    public ViewModels.NestedViewModel ViewModel {get; set;}

    public SomeView()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    
        // when viewmodel already created
        if (Mvx.IoCProvider.TryResolve<ViewModels.NestedViewModel>(out var someViewModel))
        {
             ViewModel = someViewModel;
             BindingContext = ViewModel;
             return;
        }

        // creating viewmodel
        var _viewModelLoader = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
        var request = new MvxViewModelInstanceRequest(typeof(ViewModels.NestedViewModel));
        request.ViewModelInstance = _viewModelLoader.LoadViewModel(request, null);
        ViewModel = request.ViewModelInstance as ViewModels.NestedViewModel;
        BindingContext = ViewModel;

        Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<ViewModels.NestedViewModel>(ViewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I ended up having to implement interfaces to support the extended functionality of the MVVMCross framework.

Comment: Hey @tony_370, I've just came back to this as I need to resolve a ViewModel inside the code behind for a DataTemplate for a List View Item, but the TryResolve fails to get the current instance.